# c++ how do I receive stream packets from internet site to my localhost

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, stream, ace

I am trying to write a program that sends stream packets to a certain listener (I am using my localhost) in UDP, using ACE.
This is in order to test my program that receives a stream of UDP datagrams from a remote peer.
So far I have managed to simulate a stream, but I don't know how to receive data using a connection of a real network.

This is a code example that sends 60 packets for the localhost, will that be enough for a sender?

```
int SendDatagram() 
{ 
    const char* message = "this is a message!\n"; 

    ACE_INET_Addr  sender    (27016, ACE_LOCALHOST); 
    ACE_INET_Addr  listener    (27015, ACE_LOCALHOST); 
    ACE_SOCK_DGRAM udp        (sender); 


    ssize_t sent;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ]; 
    size_t size = sizeof(buffer); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 60 ; i++)
    {
        sent = udp.send(message, ACE_OS_String::strlen(message) + 1, listener); 
        if (sent == -1) 
        { 
            ACE_ERROR_RETURN((LM_ERROR, ACE_TEXT("%p\n"), ACE_TEXT("send")), -1); 
        } 
        cout << "sent:     " << sent << " bytes" << endl;
    }

    udp.close(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: "UDP" and "stream" in the same sequence? Are you trying to spell "TCP"?

Comment: Where is sent declared? Why are you receiving packets and then checking sent instead of received - is this your real code? Anyway, did you actually test your code with a remote peer, and the peer addresses instead of `ACE_LOCALHOST`?

Comment: I meant UDP.
My program receives a stream of UDP datagrams.
You are right - the code  should be "send", bad copy paste...

Comment: Can you make your question more specific?  And put a question mark after it? ;-)  All I can gleam from your post is "how do I write software, using ACE, that receives data from the network?", which has a very non-trivial answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check chapter 9 of the ACE Programmers Guide (see [http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0201699710/theaceorb-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201699710)) for how UDP works with ACE. See `ACE_wrappers/examples/APG/Misc_IPC` for the code that belongs to that section.

Comment: I have found a good link that helped me find a solution: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sockets-with-Adaptive-c9f5cc2b